# I am trying to get file content by php code but the browser still loading till get white screen

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am trying to read this page:
http://www.alwatan.com.sa/Articles/Detail.aspx?ArticleID=25998

I used file_get_contents php function.

then used curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
'Host: adfoc.us',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*//**;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
'Connection:keep-alive',
'Host:adfoc.us',
'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0 FirePHP/0.7.4',
);    

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies1.txt');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies1.txt');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
$fileContents=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo($fileContents);
```

but the same problem.

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: where can i get error log?

Comment: It depends on the server. I'd start with the `/var/log/` directory on Linux.

Comment: removed some unnecessary stuff, working, [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZvIDHX)

Comment: from my server can not read it? may they blocked my IP or My server blocked them?

Comment: I uploaded the code to another server and it works find, what's the issue?

Comment: If the problem is only on one server, that servers IP is probably blocked at the server the page you want to request is on.

Comment: Why, just 3 or 4 times request to that server? also, how can i fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

From your `$header` array remove both "Host" key value pairs, then it works:

```
$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*//**;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
'Connection:keep-alive',
'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0 FirePHP/0.7.4',
);
```

Comment: I uploaded the code to another server and it works find, what's the issue?

Comment: With Host specified, it returns `HTTP 404 Not Found` error, there may be a few cases when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$fileContents=curl_exec($ch);
//checked this has error
if (curl_errno($ch))
{
 // echo this error
  echo curl_error($ch);

}
curl_close($ch);
```